# C# WPF (MahAppsMetro) Application on Class Library Messes up on Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

i thought of creating a WPF project with the GUI a Separate DLL, (for theming purposes) so I Created the WPF MahAppsMetro application, made it Class Library added every Resource on a ResourceDictionary, but on the designer is not showing as it supposed to be.

When i had it as WindowsApplication and not ClassLibrary it was showing like this:
[image]
But now its showing with a default set of styles:
[image]

However when i'm Compiling it, it is rendering perfectly fine.

Whats up with the designer? Is it a bug or what

Comment: Try removing metro and adding metro references again

Comment: I Uninstalled it from Nuget Packages, and Reinstalled It, Nothing Tried a couple of things like restarting computer/ visual studio (in fact that worked once, but only once :P) but not working

Comment: I've had that behavior myself some odd times, not sure what causes it

Comment: VS is an awesome Huge complex tool. But in all this complexity, bugs occurs i guess. It needs to be fixed

Comment: I guess i will end up creating a separate Project just for designing the GUI, and Copy paste for compiling lol :/

Comment: Be patient, someone might have an answer!

Comment: Considering opening an issue on mahapps github (check if it already exists before you do)

Comment: To what resource dictiomary did you add the resources? Is that dictionary known to your wimdow? One solution to your problem would be to add an App.xaml to your library (just like the one in a WPF application project, but it will be only used at design time) and insert the required MahApps resources there.

Comment: Worked lol. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a bug on XAML Designer. The workround for me is to just Restart the Designer by killing its process.

```
taskkill /f /im xdesproc.exe
```

And after that works fine.